# Windows Store App--What is SegoeUI Stylistic Set 20?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Microsoft Documentation says this about the basics of a Windows Store Application:

"The baseline of the page header should be 5 units, or 100 pixels from the top. The left margin for the page header is 6 units, or 120 pixels. The Windows 8 page header is SegoeUI Stylistic Set 20, light weight. For more information about Stylistic Sets, see Guidelines and checklist for text and typography."

I certainly know how to set a font, font size, even a font style, but I can't find anything in Visual Studio or on Microsoft webpages which defines, illustrates, or gives an example of "SegoeUI Stylistic Set 20."

Comment: It is an OpenType option.  Available in CSS with the -ms-font-feature-settings attribute, not in XAML afaik.  [WPF has it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.stylisticset20.aspx)